# CircleCI with AWS: RequestTimeTooSkewed error

Tags: testing, amazon-web-services, time, amazon-s3, circleci

I'm running tests on CircleCI and getting this error about the time being wrong when posting to AWS S3 (via [Paperclip's S3 integration](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)).

> AWS::S3::Errors::RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.

I've tried setting up NTP or [doing a curl request](https://superuser.com/a/635024/97377) to update the time, but even root is not permissioned as it's a shared environment.

> sudo date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
>
> date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

It works fine on my local environment and in production. How can I get these tests to pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) freezing to an earlier time as part of the test framework. This was solved by arranging things so the freeze wasn't necessary here.

Discovered thanks to CircleCI's attentive support.